# Not getting email notification

Tags: support, email-notification

How and where do I enable email notification here?  Despite asking and answering questions for several days, I have yet to get a single email from SO.  Is there a configuration page I blindly missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way to enable this option.

Go to your profile page -> Click on Prefs -> And the check the box: *I'd like email notifications of activity on questions I've asked*

Comment: This solution hasn't worked for me. I have the Prefs set up with that checkbox and still I never get any notifications if I ask a question and it gets answered.

Comment: @East: You won't get notification instantly. You would get it once a day.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't ask anything in Stack Overflow, only answered.

Currently it's possible to get daily email notifications for answers posted by others in your own Questions, all other activities such as comments to your answers or comments directed at you can be seen only in the global StackExchange Inbox, in the upper left corner.